# How to create a dropdown on NonFactors.Mvc.Grid row?

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5, nonfactors-mvc-grid

I want to create a dropdown on each row of the grid like the one shown in the picture. However, the action links are not rendering in a proper way. What could I do? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkwgl.png)

This is how I have tried it:

```
@(
                Html.Grid(Model).Build(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Add(m => m.ProjectName).Titled("Project");
                        columns.Add(m => m.DocumentName).Titled("Document Name");
                        columns.Add(m => m.DocumentType).Titled("Document Type");
                        columns.Add(m => m.DocumentSection).Titled("Document Section");
                        columns.Add(m => Html.ActionLink(" View More", "ViewMore", "Documents", new { id = m.DocumentID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" }));
                        columns.Add(m => Html.ActionLink(" Download", "DownloadFiles", "Documents", new { id = m.DocumentName }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }));
                        **columns.Add(m => Html.ActionLink(" Back to Project", "Index", "ProjectDetails", new { id = m.ProjectNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary" }));
                        columns.Add(m => $"<div class=\"dropdown\"><a class=\"btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle\" href=\"#\" role=\"button\" id=\"dropdownMenuLink\" data-bs-toggle=\"dropdown\" aria-expanded=\"false\">Actions</a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu\" aria-labelledby=\"dropdownMenuLink\"><li><a class=\"dropdown-item\" href=\"#\">{Html.ActionLink(" View More", "ViewMore", "Documents", new { id = m.DocumentID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })}</a></li><li><a class=\"dropdown-item\" href=\"#\">{Html.ActionLink(" Download", "DownloadFiles", "Documents", new { id = m.DocumentName }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })} </a></li> <li><a class=\"dropdown-item\" href=\"#\">{Html.ActionLink(" Back to Project", "Index", "ProjectDetails", new { id = m.ProjectNumber }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary" })}</a></li></ul></div>").Encoded(false);**
                    }).Pageable(pager =>
                    {
                        pager.PageSizes = new Dictionary<Int32, String> { { 0, "All" }, { 5, "5" }, { 10, "10" } };
                        pager.ShowPageSizes = true;
                        pager.CurrentPage = 1;
                        pager.RowsPerPage = 5;
                    })
                    )
```